# Markdown PDF output Text alignment

Tags: r, alignment, markdown

I am trying to create a pdf report using R knitr & markdown and need to pull some lines of text from a txt file. The below code chunk does the job but unfortunately, the text in the pdf is aligned right and I cannot get it to align left.

**Code:**

```
{print(fdr, header=TRUE, sep =" ")
}
```

The text is a table with a header and 3 columns and 3 rows. The text in each column is aligned to the right and would like them to be aligned to the left. I tried posting output and desired output but cannot format it right. Tried several things but unsuccessful. Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: If you can load the text file into a data frame (or convert it to a data frame), try `knitr::kable(fdr, align="lll")`

Comment: Thank you so much. This solved my problem. The table is kind of centered to the page but that is not an issue. Appreciate your help. Please post it as an answer and I will accept it.